# Refreshing a CSS animation on click

Tags: jquery, css, animation, rotation

I'm trying to make a box rotate 360° by clicking a sign that says "spin". I've used CSS3 keyframe animations and applied the CSS to a jQuery function, but the sign only triggers the animation once; it won't rotate when it's clicked the second time.

HTML:

```
<div id="box"></div>

<a class="activate">spin</a>
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".activate").click(function() {
    $('#box').css({
        "-webkit-animation-name":"cycle",
        "-webkit-animation-duration":"2s",
        "-webkit-animation-iteration-count":"1",
        "-webkit-animation-fill-mode" : "forwards",

        "animation-name":"cycle",
        "animation-duration":"2s",
        "animation-iteration-count":"1",
        "animation-fill-mode" : "forwards",

        "-moz-animation-name":"cycle",
        "-moz-animation-duration":"2s",
        "-moz-animation-iteration-count":"1",
        "-moz-animation-fill-mode" : "forwards",
    });
});
});
```

CSS:

```
#box {
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    background-color:black;
    margin-bottom:10px;
}

@-webkit-keyframes cycle {
    from {-webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);}
    to {-webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);}
}

@keyframes cycle {
    from {transform: rotate(0deg);}
    to {transform: rotate(360deg);}
}

@-moz-keyframes cycle {
    from {-moz-transform: rotate(0deg);}
    to {-moz-transform: rotate(360deg);}
}

.activate {
    margin-top:5px;
    padding:3px 5px;
    background-color:#333;
    color:#eee;
    cursor:pointer;
}
```

[Here's my JSFiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/Fenneltail/u9029a8p/)

I've looked all over StackOverflow and found nothing; do I have to use addClass and trigger + reset the animation that way?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the best way u can achieve this.

Make active class for animation

```
#box.active {
    -webkit-animation-name: cycle;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 2s;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    animation-name: cycle;
    animation-duration: 2s;
    animation-iteration-count: 1;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    -moz-animation-name: cycle;
    -moz-animation-duration: 2s;
    -moz-animation-iteration-count: 1;
    -moz-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
```

and remove active class everytime after animation end using JQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".activate").click(function() {
        $('#box').addClass('active');
        $('#box').one('webkitAnimationEnd mozAnimationEnd MSAnimationEnd oanimationend animationend',function(){
        $(this).removeClass('active');
        });

    });
});
```

[**jsfiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/u9029a8p/1/)

Comment: It worked like a charm! Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Second time it does not animate becuase it has already `style` defined.
Just clear it be before assigning `style` using `CSS`.

[image: style added on click]

For some reason if `style` remove and added again instantly it did not worked, so have to put a `setTimeout`. Event if you put an `alert` just before reassigning `style` it will work.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".activate").click(function() {

      // Find target element
      var targetElement = document.getElementById('box')

      // Remove style attribute to clear previous animation
      targetElement.removeAttribute('style');

      // setTimeout is used to fix unknown reason that needs a halt.
      // An 'alert' also makes it working
      setTimeout(function(){

        // Use target element instead of finding element again by jQuery selector
        $( targetElement ).css({
            "-webkit-animation-name":"cycle",
            "-webkit-animation-duration":"2s",
            "-webkit-animation-iteration-count":"1",
            "-webkit-animation-fill-mode" : "forwards",

            "animation-name":"cycle",
            "animation-duration":"2s",
            "animation-iteration-count":"1",
            "animation-fill-mode" : "forwards",

            "-moz-animation-name":"cycle",
            "-moz-animation-duration":"2s",
            "-moz-animation-iteration-count":"1",
            "-moz-animation-fill-mode" : "forwards",
        });

      }, 0);

  });
});
```

```css
#box {
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    background-color:black;
    margin-bottom:10px;
}

@-webkit-keyframes cycle {
    from {-webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);}
    to {-webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);}
}

@keyframes cycle {
    from {transform: rotate(0deg);}
    to {transform: rotate(360deg);}
}

@-moz-keyframes cycle {
    from {-moz-transform: rotate(0deg);}
    to {-moz-transform: rotate(360deg);}
}

.activate {
    margin-top:5px;
    padding:3px 5px;
    background-color:#333;
    color:#eee;
    cursor:pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="box"></div>

<a class="activate">spin</a>
```